# restart a daemon service(golang gin), it kill other service

Tags: shell, go, systemd

I have a service dbagent(golang & gin).  It is managed by systemd. Dbagent execute start-a.sh scripts. And start.sh execute another script:start-b.sh, the b script start a java service...
When i `systemctl restart dbagent`, it will kill the my java service.

golang execute start-a.sh

```golang
exec.Command("bash", "/etc/start-a.sh").Start()
```

start-a.sh

```bash
nohup /etc/start-b.sh 1>/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

start-b.sh

```bash
nohup java -jar xxxx 2>&1 &
```

when i execute `systemctl status dbagent`, the result is:

```bash
[root@core03 bin]# systemctl status dbagent-server
● dbagent-server.service - "Database Agent Server"
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/dbagent-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-06-29 12:22:09 CST; 29min ago
 Main PID: 1905 (dbagent-server)
   CGroup: /system.slice/dbagent-server.service
           ├─1905 /usr/local/dbagent-server/dbagent-server
           ├─2795 /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_301-amd64/bin/java -Xmx1500m -X
```

So when i restart dbagent(pid:1905 ), the child process(pid: 2795)also will be killed.

How can i avoid kill the other service when i restart dbagent? I can't change start-b.sh.

i have try:

```golang
cmd := exec.Command("bash", "/etc/start-a.sh")
cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{
   Setsid: true, //Setpgid also try
}
cmd.Start()
```

```golang
cmd := exec.Command("setsid", "/etc/start-a.sh")
cmd.Start()
```

```golang
cmd := exec.Command("bash", "/etc/start-a.sh & disown")
```

change start-a.sh

```bash
setsid /etc/start-b.sh
```

They don't work.

Comment: Are you saying if you restart 10 times you want to have 11 copies of this java process running?